# Multiprocess several files

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

i have a code that processes about 60 files in sequence. To improve performance, I would like to compute as much as possible in parallel.

This is my code:

```
def calculate:
      for file in sorted(entries.glob("*.TXT")):
            file = str(file)
            if file.endswith('Blk.TXT') or file.endswith('BLK_.TXT'):
                outlier.outlier_Cu_blk(file)
            elif file.endswith('.TXT') and 's' in file:
                outlier.outlier_Cu_std(file)
            else:
                outlier.outlier_Cu_sample(file)
```

this function calls some pandas and numpy operations.

How can I insert multiprocessing here?

Edit: the suggestion of Roland Smith works so far, however, "sorted" doesn't work anymore since some files are faster than others. But this is crucial.
And since I'm using several functions, the "if *name* = *main*" doesn't work/I don't know how to make it work

Here a bit more detail:

This is my full code:

```
def calculate(elements):       

    elif elements == available_elements[1]: ## this is just a dummy for further calculations later on

        entries = Path(inf)
        for file in entries.glob("*.exp"):
            print(file)
            outlier.outlier_Fe(file)
            print(calculate_Fe)

    elif elements == available_elements[2]: ## this is the main/only working function right now
        print('Processing the ' + available_elements[2] + ' Isotope System')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Start with outlier correction')
        entries = Path(inf)
        for file in sorted(entries.glob("*.TXT")): 
            file = str(file)
            if file.endswith('Blk.TXT') or file.endswith('BLK_.TXT'):
                outlier.outlier_Cu_blk(file)
            elif file.endswith('.TXT') and 's' in file:
                outlier.outlier_Cu_std(file)
            else:
                outlier.outlier_Cu_sample(file)
        print('Outlier correction finished')
        """Insert Header"""        
        outname = os.path.join(outfile_results, 'Cu_header.csv')
        fullname = os.path.join(outfile_results, 'Cu_export.csv')
        reread = pd.read_csv(fullname, sep='\t', names = ['Time', 'Filename', '60Ni', '61Ni', '62Ni', '63Cu', '64Ni', '65Cu', '66Zn'], index_col=False)
        reread.to_csv(fullname, sep = '\t', header=True, index=False)
        print('Calculate d65/63Cu with SSB Method')
        resultname = os.path.join(outfile_results, 'Cu_delta.csv')
        ssb.ssb()
        print('Processing of ' + available_elements[2] + ' Isotope System finished')
        print('File "'+ outname +'" contains the raw isotope values')
        print('File "'+ resultname +'" contains the d65/63Cu values')
```

This is for example happening in "outlier.py"

```
def outlier_Cu_sample(file, append=True):
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', names=['Time', '60Ni', '61Ni', '62Ni', '63Cu', '64Ni', '65Cu', '66Zn'], skiprows=6, nrows=80, index_col=False, dtype=float)
    
    cols = list(data.drop(columns='Time').columns)
    datao = pd.DataFrame({'Time':data['Time']})
    datao[cols] = data[cols].where(np.abs(stats.zscore(data[cols])) < 2)
    datao.to_csv(outfile_corrected_raw_data + basename + '.csv', sep='\t', header = True, index_label='Index_name') ## this creates single files in a folder again in the right order because of the filename

#This below here inserts the mean value of all files in a single csv file. If I do it in sequence, this is because of "sorted" in the right order. With multiprocessing it is in the wrong order. #

mean_filtered_transposed = pd.DataFrame(data=np.mean(datao)).T
mean_filtered_transposed['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(mean_filtered_transposed["Time"], unit='s')
clean = mean_filtered_transposed.drop(mean_filtered_transposed.columns[[0]], axis=1) 
clean.insert(0, 'Inputfile', file)

if append:
    clean.to_csv(fullname, sep='\t', mode="a", header=False, index_label='Index_name')
else:
    clean.to_csv(fullname, sep='\t', mode="w", header=True, index_label='Index_name')
```

How can I get this in the right order with multiprocessing? I thought about to put the steps with "mean_filtered" in another function, which is running in sequence. But how do I call the main function with the multiprocessing? In the future I need to be able to choose "element".

Edit 2: This is the multiprocessing function within /modules:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('')
import multiprocessing as mp
import modules.config as conf

infile = (conf.WorkspaceVariableInput)
def Cu(file):
    global infile
    global outfile
    inf = infile
    global outfile_results 
    global outfile_corrected_raw_data
    global outfile_plt
    

    file = str(file)
    if file.endswith('Blk.TXT') or file.endswith('BLK_.TXT'):
        outlier.outlier_Cu_blk(file)
    elif file.endswith('.TXT') and 's' in file:
        outlier.outlier_Cu_std(file)
    else:
        outlier.outlier_Cu_sample(file)
    return f"finished processing {file}"

entries = Path(infile)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = sorted(entries.glob("*.TXT"))

    with mp.Pool() as p:
        for res in p.imap_unordered(Cu, data):
            print(res)
```

it is called by this function from folder /

```
import modules.config as conf
import modules.Cu as Cu

def element(elements):
global infile
    global outfile
   # global available_elements
   # global calc
    inf = infile
    global outfile_results #= outfile + '/results'
    global outfile_corrected_raw_data
    global outfile_plt
    global export

    if elements == available_elements[2]:
        print('Processing the ' + available_elements[2] + ' Isotope System')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Start with outlier correction')
        Cu.Cu()
        print('Outlier correction finished')
        """Insert Header"""
        Cu.Cu()

chooseelement = element(str('Cu'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `for` loop from `calculate`, but put `sorted(entries.glob("*.TXT"))` in a list.
Change `calculate` to accepc a single argument, a filename.

Then create a `multiprocessing.Pool`.
Run the `Pool.imap_unordered` method using `calculate` and the list as arguments.

The main reason for using `imap_unordered` is that it returns results in the order they *finish*, whereas `map`  returns results in the order they are *submitted*. So `imap_unordered` often finishes faster.
If keeping the order of the submissions is important, use `map`.

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def calculate(file):
        if file.endswith('Blk.TXT') or file.endswith('BLK_.TXT'):
            outlier.outlier_Cu_blk(file)
        elif file.endswith('.TXT') and 's' in file:
            outlier.outlier_Cu_std(file)
        else:
            outlier.outlier_Cu_sample(file)
        return f"finished processing {file}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = sorted(entries.glob("*.TXT"))

    with mp.Pool() as p:
        for res in p.imap_unordered(calculate, data):
            print(res)
```

**Edit:**

You should *only* use `multiprocessing` objects within the main script, i.e. where `__name__ == '__main__'` is `True`.
The reason for this is found in the programming guidelines for `multiprocessing` in the documentation.

On the ms-windows and macOS platforms, `mulitprocessing` spawns a new Python interpreter for every `multiprocessing.Process` or pool worker. (The technical reason for that is that ms-windows doesn't have the `fork` system call found in POSIX systems and that some of the macOS frameworks doen't always work well with `fork`.)
This start method **requires** that the original code can be *imported* by the newly started Python interpreter *without side effects* such as trying to start a new process. Not meeting this requirement would lead to a cascade of Python processes if left unchecked.

Comment: Thx, that workes so far, however, the "sorted" doesn't work anymore, because some files are shorter than others. Thus, these files are faster. I edited my post

Comment: If I place this function as a module in a module folder it doesn't work anymore. If I call the function from another function then I get the error "missing 1 required positional argument: 'file'". If I try to start it directly from the module folder it just does nothing. If I place it in the main folder and execute it then it will run as expected. See above as "edit 2".

Comment: @Nobody See updated answer. Normally faster execution is preferred, hence my use of `imap_unordered`.

Comment: @Nobody using the main script is a requirement for `multiprocessing` to work properly on some platforms. See updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much. However, even using "p.map" doesn't give the initial order read by "sorted".

Comment: If you want the "initial order read by `sorted`", then simply remove `sorted`.

Comment: Another question: In "outlier.outlier_Cu_sample(file)" I have the variables "data", "data2" and "data3", while outlier.outlier_Cu_std(file) and outlier.outlier_Cu_blk(file) only has "data". Do I need to edit this line: "for res in p.imap_unordered(Cu, data)" ?